# Need help expanding an array within a queue

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I need to create a queue for an assignment in which I was given a template. I need it to automatically reallocate data into a new array whenever it becomes full, but I can't figure out how to do that. Here's the part I'm working on:

```
// Expand the array to double its current size if the queue is full and reallocate the array
private expand()
{
        String[]newArray = new String[maxSize*2];
        int temp = -1;
        for (int i=head; i<=tail; i++)
        {
            temp = temp +1;
            newArray[temp] = data[i];
        }
        data = newArray;
    return ;
}
```

The ArrayQueue class is as follows:

```
public class ArrayQueue implements JFQueue
{
    private int maxSize = 5; //maximum queue size
    int head; //Location of the head or first element
    int tail; //Location of the last element
    int size; //number of elements in the queue
    String[] data; //Array to hold the data

    /** Constructor
    @param maxSize sets up the maximum queue size
     */
    public ArrayQueue(int maxSize)
    {
        maxSize = maxSize;
        head = -1;
        tail = -1;
        size = 0;
        data = new String[maxSize];
    }

    // Add an element to the end of the queue
    public boolean queue(String s)
    {
        if (size == maxSize)
        {
            expand();
            return false;
        }
        else if (tail == maxSize -1 && head != 0)
        {
            tail = 0;
            data[tail] = s;
            size = size+1;
            if (head == -1){
                head = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            size = size + 1;
            tail = tail + 1;
            data[tail] = s;
            if (head == -1)
            {
                head = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    // Remove the element at the front of the queue
    public String deQueue()
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Queue is empty");
        }
        else if (head == maxSize -1)
        {
            head = 0;
            size = size - 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            size = size-1;
            head = head + 1;
        }
        return data[head];
    }

    // Return the size of the queue
    public int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    // Return the size of the queue
    public int getArraySize()
    {
        return maxSize;
    }

    // The traverse method verify that we correctly implemented the queue
    public void traverse()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Array Location " +(head + i)%maxSize +" Value "+
                data[(head + i)%maxSize]);
        }
    }

    // Expand the array to double its current size if the queue is full and reallocate the array
    private expand()
    {
            String[]newArray = new String[maxSize*2];
            int temp = -1;
            for (int i=head; i<=tail; i++)
            {
                temp = temp +1;
                newArray[temp] = data[i];
            }
            data = newArray;
        return ;
    }

    // Reduce the size of the array to half if it is only 10% full and reallocate the array
    //     private compact()
    //     {
    // 
    //     }
}
```

I feel like I could figure out the compact function if I could get the expand function to work, but I am not sure what would be returned, nor what the method type is. Help would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: the problem is in your expanding method or ?

Comment: I believe so. The queue works as needed, but he gave us just the framework for it (private expand() {} basically). When I compiled it without the return statement, it said I needed one, and does not run. He said we were not to make changes to the original code if possible. Could I be missing something?

Comment: Actually you are missing return type in this method, as you are modifying the actual array, put after private - void, so it should be private void expand(){}

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. My bad. I believe it was his fault, he probably left out 'void' when declaring the method. I changed around some things as well and added the void to get rid of the return statement and it worked. Sorry, thanks though

Comment: Thank you, I see that now. I believe he left that out when he prepared the skeleton code, but that definitely got it working. Thanks

Comment: No problem, but ask anyway the teacher exactly what are his/her requierments, there is nothing wrong with asking :)

Comment: It seems as you have forgotten to update `maxSize` in the `expand` method. Been there, done that, didn't like it.